# default values in functions used in for_each

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl, function-pointers

I tried to use `for_each` with `boost::trim`. In the first place I used a wrong code

```
 std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),&boost::trim<std::string>));
 // error: too few arguments to function
```

then I fixed (reading online) with this

```
 std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end()
              ,boost::bind(&boost::trim<std::string>,_1,std::locale()));
```

How the compiler works when it needs to pass this function to `for_each`. I thought that since `std::locale` is the default parameter for the second input argument of `boost::trim` my code should have worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default arguments are applied when you *call* a function, but they don't form part of the function signature. In particular, when you call a function through a function pointer, you have generally lost the information which default arguments are available:

```
void (*f)(int, int);

void foo(int a, int b = 20);
void bar(int a = 10, int = -8);

f = rand() % 2 == 0 ? foo : bar;
f();   // ?
```

The upshot is that to use `bind` on `f` you will always need to populate both parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can always write it using a lambda:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string & s) { boost::trim(s); });
```

Now compiler will have enough knowledge to use default parameters.